# How to call an Excel report from an other Excel report?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, alm

I have 12 Excel reports in my Application Lifecycle Management.
Each of them execute a Query and some VBA code when I click on generate.

I was wondering if it is possible to create a single Excel report that can call each of the previously mentioned reports so that I don’t have to manually generate each of them.
Is there a way?

Otherwise I think I’ll have to regroup and recode them in one big Excel report, which would not be practical for future modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call macro from "starting file".
You need open file, start makro like bellow, close file and do the same with another

```
Application.Run "filename.xlsm!macroname"
```

EDIT:

```
    sub test()
        Workbooks.Open filepath & "\filename.xlsm"
        Application.Run "filename.xlsm!macroname"
        Windows(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Close
    end sub
```

Comment: `Sub QC_PostProcessing()
Application.Run "filename.xlsm!ANA1"
End Sub`

It says it Error: can't find "filename.xlsm"; it's looking in my PC storage instead of looking in the Application Lifecycle Management storage.

Comment: I edit my answer - filename is name of your report file, filepath is path where is your report file